# How can I count the numbers of rows that a phalcon query returned?

Tags: php, phalcon

How can I count the numbers of rows that a mysql query returned? using PHP Phalcon Framework ..

**My Query**

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM robots ORDER BY name");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try like this [**Documentation Here**](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Db_Result_Pdo.html)

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM robots ORDER BY name");
echo 'There are ', $result->numRows(), ' rows in the resulset';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM robots ORDER BY name");
  $result->setFetchMode(Phalcon\Db::FETCH_NUM);
```

**Refer :**
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Db.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo $result->numRows();
 print_r($result->fetchAll());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to count the resultset

```
$result->count();
```

or

```
count($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM robots ORDER BY name");
echo $result->numRows();
```